# display available size on hover, in woocommerce shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am customizing the Woocommerce Storefront theme.
In the product-list pages (category page, shop page), I would like to display the available sizes of the product when the user hover with its mouse on the image of a product.
So I need to add html/php code that will display this on hover:

**Available sizes:**

**S, M, L, XL**

or

**Sold out**

**Notify me when the product is in stock**

I would like to do this in the functions.php of my child theme.

Should I use this hook to add html ?

```
woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title
```

I have started to code this, but I need help to go

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
/**
 * WooCommerce Loop Product Thumbs
 **/
 if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
 }
/**
 * WooCommerce Product Thumbnail
 **/
 if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {

    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog', $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0  ) {
        global $post, $woocommerce;

        $output = '<div class="imagewrapper">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size ); 

        } else {

            $output .= '<img src="'. woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() .'" alt="Placeholder" width="' . $placeholder_width . '" height="' . $placeholder_height . '" />';

        }

        //$product .=  wc_get_product($post->ID ) ;
        //$name .= $product->get_name();

        $output .= '<div class="sizeAvailHover">';
        //$output .= $name;
        $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= '</div>';

        return $output;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code I finally used for those interested:

```
/* This snippet removes the action that inserts thumbnails to products in the loop
 * and re-adds the function customized with our wrapper in it.
 * It applies to all archives with products.
 *
 * @original plugin: WooCommerce
 * @author of snippet: Brian Krogsard
 */

remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action(    'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

/**
 * WooCommerce Loop Product Thumbs
 **/

 if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail' ) ) {
    function woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
        echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();
    } 
 }

/**
 * WooCommerce Product Thumbnail
 **/

 if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ) {

    function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( $size = 'shop_catalog', $placeholder_width = 0, $placeholder_height = 0  ) {
        global $post, $wp_query, $woocommerce, $attributes;
        // if ( ! $placeholder_width ) {
        //  $placeholder_width = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_width' );
        // }
        // if ( ! $placeholder_height ){
        //  $placeholder_height = $woocommerce->get_image_size( 'shop_catalog_image_height' );
        // }

        $output = '<div class="imagewrapper">';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $size ); 

        } else {

            $output .= '<img src="'. woocommerce_placeholder_img_src() .'" alt="Placeholder" width="' . $placeholder_width . '" height="' . $placeholder_height . '" />';

        }

        //$product .=  wc_get_product($post->ID ) ;
        //$name .= $product->get_name();

        $output .= '<div class="sizeAvailHover">';
        //$output .= $name;
        //$product .=  wc_get_product($post->ID ) ;
        $product = wc_get_product( $wp_query->post );


        //echo get_post_format();

            // echo 'total stock : ';
            // echo $product->is_in_stock();



        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // $attributes .= $product->list_attributes();
            // echo print_r($attributes);
            // $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            // echo print_r($attributes);
            // $attributes .= $product->wc_display_product_attributes();
            // echo print_r($attributes);
            // $attributes .= $product->get_variation_attributes();
            // echo print_r($attributes);


            if($product->is_in_stock()) {
                $output .= ' Available sizes: <br/>';
                $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
                $i = 0;
                foreach($variations as $variation){
                    $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
                    $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
                    $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
                    //echo $stock;
                    // echo '--';
                    //echo $variation_obj->get_sku();
                    //echo print_r($variation_obj->get_variation_attributes());
                    $dummy = $variation_obj->get_variation_attributes();
                    //echo gettype($stock);
                    if ((is_int($stock) || ctype_digit($stock)) && (int)$stock > 0 ) { // int }
                    //if ($stock > 0 ) {
                        //echo $variation_obj->get_attributes();
                        //echo 'yesssss';
                        // echo print_r($dummy['attribute_pa_size']);
                        $output .= '<span class="availSize">' . strtoupper($dummy['attribute_pa_size']) . '</span>';
                    } else {
                        // echo print_r($dummy['attribute_pa_size']);
                        $output .= '<span class="unavailSize">' . strtoupper($dummy['attribute_pa_size']) . '</span>';
                    }
                    if(++$i !== count($variations)) {
                        $output .= ', ';
                    }

                    //echo '<br/>';

                }
            } else {
                $output .= ' Sold out<br/>Notify me when the product is back in stock';
            }


            // if ( ! $attributes ) {
            //     echo "No attributes";
            // }
            // foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

         //        echo $attribute['name'] . ": ";
         //        $product_attributes = array();
         //        $product_attributes = explode('|',$attribute['value']);

         //        $attributes_dropdown = '<select>';

         //        foreach ( $product_attributes as $pa ) {
         //            $attributes_dropdown .= '<option value="' . $pa . '">' . $pa . '</option>';
         //        }

         //        $attributes_dropdown .= '</select>';

         //        echo $attributes_dropdown;
            // }
        }

        $output .= '</div>';

        $output .= '</div>';

        return $output;
    }
 }
```

Comment: In the shop page, its ok but it show the available size always and not on hover, and the size variant are not centered on image but appear before the product title. it would be great if you could see the sizes available like this:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfgYH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfgYH.png)

Comment: Hi - I guess this was meant as a reply to Louis's answer? You should just be able to apply a few CSS styles to the generated HTML for the hover overlay.

Comment: @Matteo do not post comments as solutions/answers to questions. I understand you do not have enough reputation  to comment yet, but that does not mean it is okay  to abuse the system by posting a reply as a solution

Comment: Also this site is not a WooCommerce support route. For help with 3rd party plugins and themes you need to contact their support routes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The `woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail` is hooked into the `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title` action, so that would be a good way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks @finitesource, can you help me by giving me some code ?

Comment: I am gonna suggest some code, maybe you can help go further

Comment: Can someone help me with the code ? knowing I am using WooCommerce 3.1.2